# How to Set Image as a Variable in Php and display the image in HTML using that variable

Tags: php, html

So i have a query running and i get results in a while loop. In the while loop I want to set $image as a variable for a image that is needed to be displayed on a html page, by using the variable. I am not able to get the image displayed on the html.

By the way the images are located in the folder.

PHP Code :

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $image = "<img src='images/image1.png'>";
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<?php include 'File.php';?>
 <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `$image = "<img src='images/image1.png'>";` to `$image = "images/image1.png";`
and then do:

```
echo '<img src="' . $image . '"/>';
```

or in your case

```
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;"/>
```